# PDF generation in Salesforce - Conga alternatives

Tags: pdf, conga, conga-composer

**Background**

We are currently using Conga for PDF generation. We might want to decommission our Conga and move to a different solution (for licensing reasons).

**Question**

What other solutions allow the generation of PDFs based on Word Files?

Comment: Drawloop is one. Search on appexchage and you will find many. Unless things have changed don't bother with adobe's offering. Could never get it to work on install (their error) and support had no interest in troubleshooting.

Answer (score 3):

We recently launched our powerful Salesforce integration at www.outfit.io . We allow designers to build web and print ready branded templates, that you access from within Salesforce by pressing a button to create on demand, on brand, print ready docs from your SF data, or you can bulk create thousands of branded documents from scoped records in SF. If data driven personalised branded documents at scale from within Salesforce is what you're after, Outfit will do the job.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE, best of luck in your business.

Answer (score 2):

I've had a good experience with WebMerge:

https://webmerge.me

Pros:

- Flat pricing regardless of #of users
- Ability to generate other document types (XML, HTML etc)

Cons:

- Not as neatly integrated into SF as Conga
- Support could be better